Invalid `prisma.product.findMany()` invocation when deployed on Vercel
I'm trying to deploy my site after have added prisma, but keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix this.
PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.product.findMany()` invocation:
Raw query failed. Code: `unknown`. Message: `Kind: Server selection timeout: No available servers. Topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Set Name: atlas-3d8clu-shard-0, Servers: [ { Address: ac-fysecpf-shard-00-01.7qknsd4.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: received fatal alert: InternalError, labels: {} }, { Address: ac-fysecpf-shard-00-00.7qknsd4.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: received fatal alert: InternalError, labels: {} }, { Address: ac-fysecpf-shard-00-02.7qknsd4.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: received fatal alert: InternalError, labels: {} } ] }, labels: {}`
    at _n.handleRequestError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:121:7749)
    at _n.handleAndLogRequestError (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:121:7057)
    at _n.request (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:121:6741)
    at async l (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:130:9355)
    at async j (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/produto/[id].js:1:2826)
    at async buildStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:786:33)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1215:110
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:151:20) {
  code: 'P2010',
  clientVersion: '5.18.0',
  meta: {
    modelName: 'Product',

I checked everything, I searched on Google but nothing looks like that

I also created a discussion about this on github -> https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/25110


I found a github issue that might help you

Another error,
PrismaClientInitializationError:
Invalid prisma.product.findMany() invocation:
The provided database string is invalid. MongoDB connection string error: cannot use SRV-style URI with directConnection=true in database URL. Please refer to the documentation in https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls for constructing a correct connection string. In some cases, certain characters must be escaped. Please check the string for any illegal characters.

The problem was on getStaticPaths function, instead of passing the id, I passed the object
export async function getStaticPaths() { 
   const productsIds = await prisma.product.findMany(); 
   return {
      paths: productsIds.map((id) => ({
      params: { id: id.toString() },
    })),
fallback: true, // false or "blocking"
};

The correction:
export async function getStaticPaths() {
const productsIds = await prisma.product.findMany({
    select: {id: true},
  });

  return {
    paths: productsIds.map((product) => ({
      params: { id: product.id.toString() },
    })),
    fallback: 'blocking', // false or "blocking"
  };
}

